# How to install Tensorflow and Keras in R?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

After weeks of pain, I cannot use Tensorflow and Keras in R. More I read to solve it and more I am confused. I would like to know the steps to install it correctly.

Do I need to install Anaconda, tensorflow and Keras under Conda first ? Do I need to create a conda env and activate it under Conda?

Under R I tried so many way to install and each time it does not work. The problem is Tensorflow is installed in r-reticulate folder but R cannot find it.

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-setup-keras-and-tensorflow-in-rstudio-on-windows-d0175e9a8f10    Give this a read . it's easy to understand hope you install it this time

Comment: It is what I done but when I run reticulate::py_config() to check the config, tensorflow is not found

Comment: Can you trying doing it with an old version of TF 1.13.1 but use Python 3.6